# How to make a Dictionary accessible from all controllers in a .Net 5 API?

Tags: api, dictionary, asp.net-core

I have a Dictionary that will be populated with data from the database at startup, with a method that takes the key as a parameter, and returns the value. How to make the dictionary publicly accessible to all controllers? After searching, I learned that I would need to use Dependency Injection, but I'm failing at implementing it. Any resource that can get me on track is highly appreciated.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Nkosi Considering that someone was able to understand the question and answer it correctly, I respectfully disagree with your assessment.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I can respect that. However given that, as stated, you have very little knowledge in this topic, You will eventually learn that the provided answer is not a recommended way to approach this problem and will eventually lead to technical debt. Even the answer states that there are many ways to approach this. I recommend learning up on SOLID principles and understand why DI was the more recommended way of solving this kind of problem.

Comment: Yup, I had second thoughts answering this because I want to see a specific route taken first. But just to help, I just gave it. The answer I gave is one fast and basic way of doing it but eventually you'll find out there are other ways that might be more suitable for your specific design @Naqrah.

Comment: @Nkosi I have studied SOLID principles, and understand them well in theory. However, when I tried to implement Dependency Injection in a real application, I faced problems, hence my question. Can you please give another answer, as Jerdine's answer might have made things clearer now on what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @Naqrah update your post with the relevant details and examples of what you are actually trying to achieve and what you have tried. By itself, your current one paragraph request leaves too many variables unknown to be able to provide a more targeted answer. Hence my original statement about this being an incomplete post. I will gladly help. You however need to help us to help you. Remember we are volunteering time to assist. The least you can do is provide the relevant details for us to be able to solve your problem, otherwise we are left guessing, wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Here are some questions to help you clarify the problem. How is this dictionary to be used? Is it read only, will it be updated? Are you trying to recreate functionality that already exists in the framework? Do you even need to use a dictionary? None of that can be assessed from the currently available information, even with the answer already provided. I really do hope you understand where I am coming from with my statements. I will help where I can.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement your question with/without DI. One of which is to write a static class that will be filled upon app startup.

No dependency injection:

1. Declare a static class that contains your dictionary. By being static there would only be 1 instance on app start.

```
public static class StaticDictionary {
   public Dictionary<string,int> MyDictionary {get;set;}
}
```

2. In your Startup.cs - Configure method, append your db context in the parameters.

```
public void Configure(..., YourDbContext dbContext)
```

3. In the Configure method again, append your code that fills the dictionary.

```
public void Configure(..., YourDbContext dbContext){
   ...

   // no need to modify the code above this, just append the fill dictionary code
   foreach(var item in dbContext.TableName.ToList()){
      StaticDictionary.MyDictionary.Add(...);
   }
   
}
```

4. In your controllers, you could access StaticDictionary without DI.

```
public IActionResult Index{
   var something = StaticDictionary.MyDictionary["Something"];

   return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Follow-up question: Do I have to fill it at startup? What if I created a static method that filled the Dictionary at a later stage, will it still be accessible?

Comment: @Naqrah yes Static Class is always accessible and there's only 1 instance throughout the application, dictionary will be empty unless you fill it though.

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend a book/course that goes into details about this type of stuff? Concepts like instances, Inversion of Control, Dependency Injection, etc...

Comment: @Naqrah sorry I just literally read them off google search results. I read many sites regarding one topic so that I get to see many ways of how it is used.